# Backup database query with OS error 5

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-backups

I'm trying to run a backup query:

```
BACKUP DATABASE MY_DATABASE TO DISK='C:\Users\me\Desktop\POD2013-05-14.bak'
```

But I get the following error:

```
Cannot open backup device 'C:\Users\me\Desktop\POD2013-05-14.bak'. Operating system error 5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105).
```

I thought it has to do with permissions, but log in as `sa` and `Administrator` (Win Auth) doesn't solve the problem.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL server 2008 backup error - Operating system error 5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398385/sql-server-2008-backup-error-operating-system-error-5failed-to-retrieve-text) and [many other similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+server+backup+error+5). The SQL Server service account needs to have access to the path, and usually only your account can access your own desktop. It would be best to use a different folder, and grant the SQL Server service account access to it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the security permissions on the folder you are trying to backup. Make sure the service account (Network Service) has write permissions.

I think your problem might be okay.