# Error in backing up database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, backup

I want to backup a database from our main server. But this error happens

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open backup device 'C:\Temp\sample.bak'. Operating system error 3 (The system cannot find the path specified.).
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
>   ClientConnectionId:d9c1c173-e60e-4e07-91d6-2ba43b905ff6

Thank you for your help!

The query I tried is

```
BACKUP DATABASE H2RPDB_v2 
TO DISK = 'C:\Temp\test2.bak'
```

in SQL Server. `H2RPDB_v2` is from my remote server.

Comment: If you run a backup on a **remote** server, then the backup file will be created **on that remote server's filesystem** - where maybe `C:\temp` just doesn't exist (as the error pretty clearly says - no?)

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the path doesn't exist. Does C:\Temp exist? If so, does the service account have access to the folder?

Other things might be storage is full, etc.

See related question: 
[SQL server 2008 backup error - Operating system error 5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398385/sql-server-2008-backup-error-operating-system-error-5failed-to-retrieve-text)

Comment: I can actually backup if I'm using local server. But when I'm using our remote server it doesn't work. I tried the query in the SQL Server and it didn't work.

Comment: Assuming you have appropriate access, this may do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942207/how-can-i-backup-a-remote-sql-server-database-to-a-local-drive

Comment: I mean I need to backup a file using coding not generating script. So, I'm trying the query 'Backup Database...' in SQL Server because I need to use it in C# Coding.

Comment: Could you post your query here, or update your question with your query string?

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that either C:\Temp doesn't exist, or the service account sql server is running under doesn't have access to that path. Try saving it to a path the service account has access to, or if you have RDP access to the server, see if the path exists and appropriate access exists.